# ZLib gZip compress generates corrupted result

Tags: c++, zlib

I'm trying to generate gzip compressed file from xml using the following code:

```
stream.next_in = inbuf; 
   stream.avail_in = 0; 
   stream.next_out = outbuf; 
   stream.avail_out = myBufferSize; 

   int infile_remaining = inFileSize; 

   if (deflateInit2(&stream, Z_DEFAULT_COMPRESSION, Z_DEFLATED, windowsBits  + 16, 9, Z_DEFAULT_STRATEGY) != Z_OK)
   {
      return 0;
    }

   for ( ; ; ) 
   { 
      int status; 
      if (!stream.avail_in) 
      { 
         int n = min(BUFFER_SIZE, infile_remaining); 
         if (MyFileReadFunc(pInfile, inbuf, n) != n) 
         { 
            deflateEnd(&stream);
            return -1;
         } 

         stream.next_in = inbuf; 
         stream.avail_in = n; 
         infile_remaining -= n; 
      } 

      status = deflate(&stream, infile_remaining ? Z_NO_FLUSH : Z_FINISH);
      if ((status == Z_STREAM_END) || (!stream.avail_out)) 
      { 
         int w = myBufferSize - stream.avail_out; 
         if (MyFileWriteFunc(pOutfile, outbuf, w) != w) 
         { 
            deflateEnd(&stream);
            return -1;
         } 

         stream.next_out = outbuf; 
         stream.avail_out = myBufferSize;
      }

      if (status == Z_STREAM_END) 
         break; 
      else if (status != Z_OK) 
      { 
         deflateEnd(&stream);
         return 0;
      } 
   }

   if (deflateEnd(&stream) != Z_OK) 
   { 
      return 0; 
   }
```

The input xml file I test on is 2 KB, and the result seems always corrupted.
Note: when I remove some data from the file, it seems working (Then I tested it on different input file and got the same result).

Answer (score 0):

First off, `int readed` and `int written` are not used, and `n` and `w` are not set.  Perhaps you meant `int n` and `int w`?

Second, the `else if (status != Z_OK)` is too stringent.  You may also get a `Z_BUF_ERROR`, for which you should continue, not error out.  `Z_BUF_ERROR` is not really an error, it's just a warning that no progress was made on that last call.  You can simply continue from there, providing more input and/or more output space.

Other points: you probably don't want to use `Z_SYNC_FLUSH` for every buffer.  That degrades compression needlessly, unless you have a reason to insert sync markers.  Just use `Z_NO_FLUSH`.  Also a `memLevel` of 9 may reduce compression.  You should experiment with your data.  Generally 8 (the default) works better.

Comment: Yes I updated the readed, written variables in the sample. the problem is no error returned from any call, but the generated file is corrupted.

Comment: What kind of system are you on?  Where is the rest of your code?  Are you using binary mode for the file reading and writing?

Comment: "No progress" can also mean that the uncompressed data is an exact multiple of your output buffer size (for instance 1024 bytes). In that case trying to decompress the last bytes (the sync mark) would not produce any data. But that is not a problem since you already got all the bytes! The decompressor should be aware of this and not bomb out with an error.

Comment: `Z_BUF_ERROR` is not an error. It was misnamed. It is simply a warning, and decompression operations can always continue after getting that.